# How can I play sound in Java?

Tags: java, audio

I want to be able to play sound files in my program. Where should I look?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

I wrote the following code that works fine. But I think it only works with `.wav` format.

```
public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
  // The wrapper thread is unnecessary, unless it blocks on the
  // Clip finishing; see comments.
    public void run() {
      try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
          Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/sounds/" + url));
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start(); 
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }).start();
}
```

Comment: To avoid Clip being shut down at random time, a LineListener is required. Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577724/trouble-playing-wav-in-java/577926#577926

Comment: +1 for a solution that uses the public API. Isn't creating a new thread unnecessary(redundant) though?

Comment: Thanx..

Is it redundant? I made it into a new thread so I can play the sound again before the first clip ends.

Comment: I know clip.start() spawns a new thread, so I'm pretty sure it is unnecessary.

Comment: Appears you're using javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem instead of sun.audio.* here (which is apparently better)?

Comment: 1) The `Thread` is unnecessary. 2) For a good example of using `Clip`, see the [JavaSound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info). 3) If a method requires an `URL` (or `File`) give it a dang `URL` (or `File`) rather than accept a `String` that represents one.  (Just a personal 'bee in my bonnet'.) 4) `e.printStackTrace();` provides more information with less typing than `System.err.println(e.getMessage());`.

Comment: I tried to play a .wav and it gave NullPointerException. What type of files are supported by this command?

Comment: @NoBugs a NullPointerException can be thrown for 1000 reasons. Are you sure you load the .wav correctly? Are you sure it is in the right path? IIRC, the .wav file should be inside the compiled jar. Although I might be terribly wrong.

Comment: The NullPointerException could be that you are not referencing the wav file correctly - e.g., use playSound("/bark.wav") not playSound("bark.wav")

Comment: Replace the System.err.println(...) line with e.printStackTrace() for more information on the NullPointerException.

Comment: I have my system all set up correctly, And the files in place. I get no errors. However, The sound doesn't play.. Do i need to initialize the sound system somewhere or something..?

Comment: where to the Clip, AudioSystem, and AudioInputStream classes come from?

Comment: Snappawapa: javax.sound.sampled

Comment: It looks like the `Clip` stays in memory and you create a new one with every call. So you would create a memory leak like that.

Comment: To avoid clip.drain() bug  as @yanchenko mentioned,here is a listener solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389991/drain-method-in-javas-clip-class/40429786#40429786

Comment: Nobody is closing that `InputStream`

Comment: Or the `Clip`. Yep, those are closeable too!

Answer (score 20):

A bad example:

```
import  sun.audio.*;    //import the sun.audio package
import  java.io.*;

//** add this into your application code as appropriate
// Open an input stream  to the audio file.
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(Filename);

// Create an AudioStream object from the input stream.
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);         

// Use the static class member "player" from class AudioPlayer to play
// clip.
AudioPlayer.player.start(as);            

// Similarly, to stop the audio.
AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);
```

Comment: http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html There are public API alternatives to using sun.audio.

Comment: @GregHurlman Isn't sun.* package made to be not used by us developers?

Comment: @Tom - Could be; I don't usually find myself using this sort of code.

Comment: This example comes from a 1997 JavaWorld article. Way out of date, You should NOT use sun.* packages.

Comment: do you ever need to close "in"?

Comment: +1 for *not* using the sun.* packages.  They have weird bugs like not handling files > 1MB and not being able to play one clip if the previous hasn't finished yet, etc.

Answer (score 14):

I didn't want to have so many lines of code just to play a simple damn sound. This can work if you have the JavaFX package (already included in my jdk 8).

```
private static void playSound(String sound){
    // cl is the ClassLoader for the current class, ie. CurrentClass.class.getClassLoader();
    URL file = cl.getResource(sound);
    final Media media = new Media(file.toString());
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

Notice : You need to [initialize JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025718/javafx-toolkit-not-initialized-when-trying-to-play-an-mp3-file-through-mediap). A quick way to do that, is to call the constructor of JFXPanel() once in your app :

```
static{
    JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
}
```

Comment: this is for every audio format including mp3.

Answer (score 9):

For whatever reason, the top answer by wchargin was giving me a null pointer error when I was calling this.getClass().getResourceAsStream().

What worked for me was the following:

```java
void playSound(String soundFile) {
    File f = new File("./" + soundFile);
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f.toURI().toURL());  
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioIn);
    clip.start();
}
```

And I would play the sound with:

```java
 playSound("sounds/effects/sheep1.wav");
```

sounds/effects/sheep1.wav was located in the base directory of my project in Eclipse (so not inside the src folder).

Comment: hello Anrew, your code worked for me, but i noticed that takes a little extra time in execution...about 1,5 sec.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream()` will return `null` if the resource is not found, or throw the exception if `name` is `null` - not a fault of top answer if the given path is not valid

Comment: what if the audio is non - wav ?

Comment: Loading a file from the filesystem and loading a resource from the classpath is not equivalent, even if it seems so in your IDE.

Answer (score 8):

For playing sound in java, you can refer to the following code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// To play sound using Clip, the process need to be alive.
// Hence, we use a Swing application.
public class SoundClipTest extends JFrame {

   public SoundClipTest() {
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setTitle("Test Sound Clip");
      this.setSize(300, 200);
      this.setVisible(true);

      try {
         // Open an audio input stream.
         URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("gameover.wav");
         AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
         // Get a sound clip resource.
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
         clip.open(audioIn);
         clip.start();
      } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new SoundClipTest();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a game framework sometime ago to work on Android and Desktop, the desktop part that handle sound maybe can be used as inspiration to what you need.

https://github.com/hamilton-lima/jaga/blob/master/jaga%20desktop/src-desktop/com/athanazio/jaga/desktop/sound/Sound.java

Here is the code for reference.

```
package com.athanazio.jaga.desktop.sound;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Sound {

    AudioInputStream in;

    AudioFormat decodedFormat;

    AudioInputStream din;

    AudioFormat baseFormat;

    SourceDataLine line;

    private boolean loop;

    private BufferedInputStream stream;

    // private ByteArrayInputStream stream;

    /**
     * recreate the stream
     * 
     */
    public void reset() {
        try {
            stream.reset();
            in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(stream);
            din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
            line = getLine(decodedFormat);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            line.close();
            din.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    Sound(String filename, boolean loop) {
        this(filename);
        this.loop = loop;
    }

    Sound(String filename) {
        this.loop = false;
        try {
            InputStream raw = Object.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
            stream = new BufferedInputStream(raw);

            // ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            // int read = raw.read(buffer);
            // while( read > 0 ) {
            // out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            // read = raw.read(buffer);
            // }
            // stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

            in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(stream);
            din = null;

            if (in != null) {
                baseFormat = in.getFormat();

                decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(
                        AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, baseFormat
                                .getSampleRate(), 16, baseFormat.getChannels(),
                        baseFormat.getChannels() * 2, baseFormat
                                .getSampleRate(), false);

                din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);
                line = getLine(decodedFormat);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private SourceDataLine getLine(AudioFormat audioFormat)
            throws LineUnavailableException {
        SourceDataLine res = null;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,
                audioFormat);
        res = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        res.open(audioFormat);
        return res;
    }

    public void play() {

        try {
            boolean firstTime = true;
            while (firstTime || loop) {

                firstTime = false;
                byte[] data = new byte[4096];

                if (line != null) {

                    line.start();
                    int nBytesRead = 0;

                    while (nBytesRead != -1) {
                        nBytesRead = din.read(data, 0, data.length);
                        if (nBytesRead != -1)
                            line.write(data, 0, nBytesRead);
                    }

                    line.drain();
                    line.stop();
                    line.close();

                    reset();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This code may error on `stream.reset();` leading to `Resetting to invalid mark`. What do you propose to do to fix this?

Comment: maybe recreate the stream, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573767/exception-stating-resetting-to-invalid-mark-comes-while-marking-an-inputstre

Comment: I actually resolved this by using `raw.mark(raw.available()+1)` after initialising `raw` and then in the while loop, and then using `raw.reset()` instead of `stream.reset()`. My problem now is that when it comes around to reset, there's a gap between plays. I want to achieve a continuous loop like you get with `Clip`. I'm not using `Clip` because manipulating controls such as MASTER_GAIN has a noticeable delay of ~500ms. This should probably be its own question that I'll get around to asking later.

Comment: Not a `do { ... } while`?

Answer (score 3):

It works for me. Simple variant

```
public void makeSound(){
    File lol = new File("somesound.wav");
    

    try{
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(lol));
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative to importing the sound files which works in both applets and applications: convert the audio files into .java files and simply use them in your code.

I have developed a tool which makes this process a lot easier.  It simplifies the Java Sound API quite a bit.

http://stephengware.com/projects/soundtoclass/

Comment: I used your system to create a class from a wav file, However, When i do my_wave.play(); it doesn't play the audio.. Is there an audio system i need to initialize or something?..

Comment: this would be really cool if it did actually work. When running play(), the get Audio Line fails (exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_UNSIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported." is not thrown). Sad.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody suggested using Applet. [Use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3780445/453673) `Applet`. You'll have to supply the beep audio file as a `wav` file, but it works. I tried this on Ubuntu:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        File file = new File("/path/to/your/sounds/beep3.wav");
        URL url = null;
        if (file.canRead()) {url = file.toURI().toURL();}
        System.out.println(url);
        AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
        clip.play();
        System.out.println("should've played by now");
    }
}
//beep3.wav was available from: http://www.pacdv.com/sounds/interface_sound_effects/beep-3.wav
```

Comment: `Applet` is deprecated as of Java 9.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
public class SoundClipTest{
    //plays the sound
    public static void playSound(final String path){
        try{
            final File audioFile=new File(path);
            AudioInputStream audioIn=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
            Clip clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
            long duration=getDurationInSec(audioIn);
            //System.out.println(duration);
            //We need to delay it otherwise function will return
            //duration is in seconds we are converting it to milliseconds
            Thread.sleep(duration*1000);
        }catch(LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | MalformedURLException | InterruptedException exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //Gives duration in seconds for audio files
    public static long getDurationInSec(final AudioInputStream audioIn){
        final AudioFormat format=audioIn.getFormat();
        double frameRate=format.getFrameRate();
        return (long)(audioIn.getFrameLength()/frameRate);
    }
    ////////main//////
    public static void main(String $[]){
        //SoundClipTest test=new SoundClipTest();
        SoundClipTest.playSound("/home/dev/Downloads/mixkit-sad-game-over-trombone-471.wav");
    }
}
```

Comment: [link for free sounds](https://mixkit.co/free-sound-effects/game-over/)

Comment: Compliments and thanks for the code! The duration of the sound is essential to wait/sleep until it ends!

Answer (score 0):

This thread is rather old but I have determined an option that could prove useful.

Instead of using the Java `AudioStream` library you could use an external program like Windows Media Player or VLC and run it with a console command through Java.

```
String command = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Media Player/wmplayer.exe\" \"C:/song.mp3\"";
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will also create a separate process that can be controlled it the program.

```
p.destroy();
```

Of course this will take longer to execute than using an internal library but there may be programs that can start up faster and possibly without a GUI given certain console commands.

If time is not of the essence then this is useful.

Comment: Although I think this is an objectively bad solution (in terms of reliability, efficiency, and other such metrics), it is at least an interesting one I would not otherwise have thought of!

Answer (score 0):

I faced many issues to play mp3 file format
so converted it to .wav using some [online converter](https://online-audio-converter.com/)

and then used below code (it was easier instead of mp3 supporting)

```
try
{
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(GuiUtils.class.getResource("/sounds/success.wav")));
    clip.start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LogUtils.logError(e);
}
```