# Java: Playing WAV sounds

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to build a java drum machine that needs to play WAV sound samples of the various drum parts (bass drum, snare, etc). Because I need to play the sounds in a tight sequence, I need high performance. Currently I'm using:

```
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MusicPlayer {

    private String filename;

    public MusicPlayer(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void play() {
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
            AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(as); 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }          
    }
}
```

as suggested here: [How can I play sound in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java)

While it does work faster than MP3 + Javazoom jLayer, it still sounds choppy at high tempo and when I do cpu intensive stuff like resizing the app window.

Any tips on improving performance?

BTW. I've also read that `sun.audio.*` is deprecated. Is there a similar solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [**Java Media Framework (JMF)**](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/):

> The Java Media Framework API (JMF)
>   enables audio, video and other
>   time-based media to be added to
>   applications and applets built on Java
>   technology. This optional package,
>   which can capture, playback, stream,
>   and transcode multiple media formats,
>   extends the Java 2 Platform, Standard
>   Edition (J2SE) for multimedia
>   developers by providing a powerful
>   toolkit to develop scalable,
>   cross-platform technology.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should put the sounds in cache: if you load them from disk each time you play them, it is indeed slow. Now, you might have a memory problem, but it depends on your sounds (size, number...).

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is to make a couple of extra threads.

If you can play two sounds at once then just make a buffer with 5 instances of the same sound and play the one available.