# Second audio clip does not play.

Tags: java, audio, playback, clip

Well, specifically, why this code here doesn't seem to want to play the second audio file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Plays first file for a few seconds
    playMusic(new File("C:\\sample.wav"));
    wait(5.0);
    System.out.print("...");

    //Second file that doesn't want to play:
    playMusic(new File("C:\\sample2.wav"));
}

public static void playMusic(File Stream) {
    AudioInputStream AIS
    = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Stream);

    Clip music = AudioSystem.getClip();
    music.open(AIS);
    music.start();
}
```

I figure I have to dismiss something or other (e.g. music.close(), AIS.close()), but these particular examples don't seem to have any effect. Any ideas?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  For the sounds, either generate them in memory, or hot-link to ones available on the net.  E.G. I provide some sounds through my [media page](http://pscode.org/media/#sound).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible your application terminates before your audio clip has finished playing?  You may find this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577724/trouble-playing-wav-in-java/577926#577926) helpful.

Comment: Ohohoho, yep, that's it. I feel a little silly now. Thank you, though!

Comment: Took me a moment to figure out where to click. Got it, I think.