# How to play a sound (alert) in a java application?

Tags: java, audio

I am working with a SMS handling, java based software and want to play a beep / alert sound whenever we receive a message.  I tried looking at the java.sound libraries and could not find anything.  I do not know if going the applet way of playing a sound will be okay in a java application!  Are there any predefined sounds in any java libraries which we can call in an application? Any pointers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 61):

If you just want to produce a beep or a quick alert, you can use the following code:

```java
import java.awt.Toolkit;
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
```

Comment: This might not work under Linux.

Comment: FYI, working fine on Windows 10. Thank you

Comment: works fine on ubuntu linux

Comment: not working on ubuntu 20

Answer (score 42):

You can generate your own sound if you looking for something less boring than a beep() without an external sound file.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SoundUtils {

  public static float SAMPLE_RATE = 8000f;

  public static void tone(int hz, int msecs) 
     throws LineUnavailableException 
  {
     tone(hz, msecs, 1.0);
  }

  public static void tone(int hz, int msecs, double vol)
      throws LineUnavailableException 
  {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1];
    AudioFormat af = 
        new AudioFormat(
            SAMPLE_RATE, // sampleRate
            8,           // sampleSizeInBits
            1,           // channels
            true,        // signed
            false);      // bigEndian
    SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
    sdl.open(af);
    sdl.start();
    for (int i=0; i < msecs*8; i++) {
      double angle = i / (SAMPLE_RATE / hz) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
      buf[0] = (byte)(Math.sin(angle) * 127.0 * vol);
      sdl.write(buf,0,1);
    }
    sdl.drain();
    sdl.stop();
    sdl.close();
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SoundUtils.tone(1000,100);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    SoundUtils.tone(100,1000);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    SoundUtils.tone(5000,100);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    SoundUtils.tone(400,500);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    SoundUtils.tone(400,500, 0.2);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The applet route should be fine (and is very straightforward).  To avoid creating an Applet instance you can use the static [`newAudioClip`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#newAudioClip(java.net.URL)) method, and then call `play()` on the `AudioClip` created.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/foo/bar/sound.wav");
AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
clip.play();
```

Here, the `sound.wav` file is bundled in the `jar` file in the `foo/bar` package that you create. A fully functional class (where the `wav` file is in the `sounds` package) would look like this:

```
package sounds;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;

public class PlaySound {

    public void PlayBeep() {        
        AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("/sounds/beep3.wav"));
        clip.play();
    }
}
```

Here, the path is given as `/sounds/` because when you extract the `jar`, you'll see that the `wav` file is located in the first folder in the `jar`, which is `sounds`.

Comment: any idea why this answer is not widely used? It seems extremely simple and useful...

Comment: This was an excellent solution for me.

Comment: This works in Linux.

Comment: Worked very well at first attempt!!

Answer (score 6):

You can take a look at the beep method within the Toolkit class, as shown [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/Toolkitbeep.htm)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the sound package to play an arbitrary sound file, you can use the `javax.sound.sampled` package.  Here is the code that will play a sound file:

```
private void playSound(File f) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        private File f;

        public void run() {
            playSoundInternal(this.f);
        }

        public Runnable setFile(File f) {
            this.f = f;
            return this;
        }
    }.setFile(f);

    new Thread(r).start();
}

private void playSoundInternal(File f) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);
        try {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            try {
                clip.start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                clip.drain();
            } finally {
                clip.close();
            }
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            audioInputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why we need the thread to sleep after calling clip.start()?

Comment: It's been a while since I wrote this code, but my guess is that it would probably work just as well with a `Thread.yield()`.

Comment: I was referring to why we need to block in the first place, but I realized it's probably because we'd close the line before it finishes playing

Comment: I think you actually needed to pass back to system resources in order for the clip to actually start.

Comment: Yes, it would close the line before it finishes playing.

Comment: I removed the Thread.sleep(100) and it works fine for me in a long running app. If running in a short test you might find that, without this sleep the app is actually closing and therefore terminates the thread ... maybe... so the sleep helps to keep a short lived app alive long enough for the sound to play? (but then drain() would keep the thread alive long enough to finish... hmmm - so maybe the sleep never had any purpose at all.

Comment: It didn't work without it.  I ran this in a long-running app.  The `clip.start()` would signal the clip to start, and then it acted like the `clip.drain()` canceled that before it could actually start.  Once I put the `Thread.sleep()` call in, it played.  It's quite possible that this was a bug which has been fixed since then.