# playing a sound

Tags: java

I'm very beginner in Java, so ...

I've written a simple Java code to display images from my hard drive wherever I click the mouse, not on the applet, on panel, now how can I make a sound play automatically when I view 6 pictures ?

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
            if (count == images.length - 1) { 
                    ???????????????????????
            } else { 
                    count++; 
            } 
            x = e.getX(); 
            y = e.getY(); 
            frameTest.repaint(); 
            }
```

I want to play a sound file from the Hard drive, in the place of question marks ..

can some one help plz ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Try to write this inside your if :

```
try
{
     Clip clickClip = AudioSystem.getClip();
     URL clipURL = new URL("file://C:/aFile.wav");
     AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(clipURL);
     clickClip.open(ais);
     clickClip.start();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
     System.out.ptintln("Something didn't work !\n" + e.printStackTrace());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\Jacky\My Documents\IamgeFrameTest.java:36: cannot find symbol symbol: class Clip Clip clickClip = AudioSystem.getClip(); ^ C:\Documents and Settings\Jacky\My Documents\IamgeFrameTest.java:36: cannot find symbol symbol: variable AudioSystem Clip clickClip = AudioSystem.getClip(); ^ C:\Documents and Settings\Jacky\My Documents\IamgeFrameTest.java:37: cannot find symbol symbol: class URL URL clipURL = new URL("file://C:/1.wav"); ^

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\Jacky\My Documents\IamgeFrameTest.java:37: cannot find symbol
symbol: class URL
URL clipURL = new URL("file://C:/1.wav");
                  ^
C:\Documents and Settings\Jacky\My Documents\IamgeFrameTest.java:38: cannot find symbol
symbol: class AudioInputStream
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(clipURL);
^
C:\Documents and Settings\Jacky\My Documents\IamgeFrameTest.java:38: cannot find symbol
symbol: variable AudioSystem
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(clipURL);
                       ^
6 errors

Comment: It's normal, these classes must be imported. Don't forget to add the following imports to your code: import java.net.*;import javax.sound.sampled.*;
It should work now. When you have such errors, you should check javadoc here : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html

Comment: unreported exception javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                        Clip clickClip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                                                            ^
unreported exception java.net.MalformedURLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
URL clipURL = new URL("file://C:/1.wav");
              ^

Comment: unreported exception javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(clipURL);
                                                      ^
unreported exception javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
clickClip.open(ais);
              ^
4 errors

Comment: I've imported    import java.net.*; import javax.sound.sampled.*;

Comment: all I'm importing now is import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

Comment: For the Exception issue, check the edit I've made on my post.

Comment: can u plz check this ?
I've uploded the code
i want u to add ur poart and make it run
can u ?

Comment: If you have other errors, you sometimes have to do things by yourself. The problem about playing an audio file looks resolved and thus you should mark this answer as resolved. Otherwise, post the errors you get. I'm not going to make your work buddy.