# What is the platform independent sound format in java

Tags: java, cross-platform, audio

I am working on a chat application in java. My program need to play sounds at regular interval as the message arrives. What are the sound format should I choose to play on (Windows/Linux/MacOS) platforms, without using external liberaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound-formats are all platform independent. The question is: Is there a Codec on the target platform which supports this format.

If you're developing a chat-application i guess you won't use high quality audio things, so `Sun Audio`-files should work for you. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java) older post on how to use them.

Comment: I dont want to rely on a specific codec, there are some formats supported on almost all platforms/or you can say codecs available like midi format are there other alternatives too

Comment: The `Sun Audio`-format is available on every platform that supports the JVM. It comes with the Java Installation.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason .ao seems to be the lowest common denominator for Java, while .wav  seems to be used almost everywhere else for notification-sounds (or possibly even .ogg or .mp3).

Comment: The thing with MP3 is that Java doesn't have native support for it. But you're right about .wav and .ogg

Comment: Is .wav format supported on all platforms, I thought its native to windows.