# Does java have a built in library where they have an audio file already in their library?

Tags: java, audio

can I import an API from java that plays a sound file that Oracle has in their API when a player wins a game; for example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java

Comment: Java APIs don't come with sample audio files. Try the post linked above to play your own file.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are after the 'one liner'..

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
```

Otherwise see either of the *last two* answers on the question linked by Nick Veys.  The rest of the answers are low quality IMO.