# how to make JFileChooser see and choose sound files only and save them in some place?

Tags: java, swing, audio, jfilechooser

I'm looking for a way to make a file chooser only show, and allow selecting of, sound files.
When the user chooses a sound file the program should go and save the file in some known place.

Answer (score 3):

> im looking for a way to make a file chooser only see sound files

Use a filter. See [Filtering the List of Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters).

> and when the user choose sound file the program go and save the file in some known place

Doesn't make sense to me. If the file already exists why do you want to copy it to another place. If this is your real requrement then you need to read and write the file. Read the [Java Essential Classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) tutorial which has a section on I/O.

Comment: See also [Returning a list of audio filetypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541099/returning-a-list-of-audio-filetypes/6541487#6541487) for getting Java compatible audio types.