# Java applet from jar

Tags: java, jar, applet

Had no luck getting this to work via what I found on google.

Comment: 1) Make sure to set the Jar entries to 'no compression' if it only contains images.  Zip (as used in a Jar) compression does almost nothing for images.  2) I would recommend putting the classes into a separate Jar that uses standard compression.  They will be compressed smaller and the JRE only needs to do a single connection to the server to get them all.  Why do you *not* want to put the applet in a Jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load any resource that is available on the classpath, which your jar would be a part of, using [`ClassLoader.getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

You can obtain a reference to a relevant `ClassLoader` object using `Class.getClassLoader()`

```
ClassLoader cl = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
```

If your image were named `myimage.png` and in a directory called `images` inside your jar, you could get the image like so.

```
URL url = cl.getResource("images/myimage.png");
```

You can then use the URL to create an image object in memory.

```
Image i = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
```

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).  +1 for the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Beautiful. By the way is there any analogous way to do this with audio files? Toolkit doesn't seem to cover it.

Comment: I recommend taking a look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java . Worth noting, If the methods you want to use don't accept a URL object but will take an `InputStream`. You can use the URL object to get a raw `InputStream` by calling the `openStream()` method on it. You could then pass this stream of bytes to whatever you need to.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) at the Java website may be of use to  you.

You'll do something like this:

```
java.net.URL imgURL = this.getClass().getResource(path);
```

The `getResource()` method uses the same loading rules as defined by the [`ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) for the class.