# Unable to play audio in my Java application

Tags: java, audio, netbeans, mp3, ioexception

My code:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try{
            File snd = new File("C:/music.mp3");
            AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;
            AudioStream BGM;
            AudioData MD;
            ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;
            try{
                BGM = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(snd));
                MD = BGM.getData();
                loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(MD);

            }
            catch(IOException err){    
            }

            MGP.start(loop);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }

    }
```

I am getting no errors. Its just that I'm not hearing the sound. My speakers are properly connected and volume is set to max. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java

Comment: But I think that will only play .wav files. I want to play MP3 files.

Comment: 1) *"I want to play MP3 files."*  Read the [JavaSound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for how to play MP3s using the JavaSound API. 2) *"I am getting no errors"* No, you are ***ignoring all*** errors!  In the `catch` call `printStackTrace()` on the throwable.  3) When using 3rd party APIs, it pays to link to the JavaDocs for them so people can check what exceptions the methods declare etc.

Comment: 4) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Comment: I edited my code according to what you said, @AndrewThompson
It prints `java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream`

Comment: Good.  ..I'll jump back in when you have addressed all 4 points I made.

Comment: AFAIK you can't play MP3 with JavaSE alone. You need 3rd party and your code doesn't seem to use any. I could run your code without 3rd party extension... and got errors (I added error output )

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) (JMF)and the [MP3 plugin](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html) (and optionally but recommended [Performance Pack](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/setup-138642.html) for your platform).
Then a sample code can be found [here](http://www.javareference.com/jrexamples/viewexample.jsp?id=126).
The JMF javadocs can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/)

Comment: Im getting an error -
`Exception in thread "JMF thread: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@53a9d5[ com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@53a9d5 ] ( configureThread)" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: EDIT: More errors-
  Unable to handle format: mpeglayer3, 44100.0 Hz, 16-bit, Stereo, LittleEndian, Signed, 24000.0 frame rate, FrameSize=32768 bits
Failed to realize: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@83e2ef
Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@83e2ef`

Comment: Did you check the JMF sample applications? Try to run one of them to make sure your installation of JMF is correct, including the support for MP3