# How to make musical note sounds?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that can simulate a piano.

So I need to make note sounds(Do,Re,Mi..).

Is there any simple way to implement this?

Comment: well... record the single notes an play them on click... or would you like to go via `beep(440)` ??^^

Comment: Implement a `GUI` that contains a piano, then you can play sounds when some of the components is pressed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java

Comment: I don't want to do this by playing any file :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the below java library

http://www.jfugue.org/

all you can obtain without using third part library or writing a quite complex code (perhaps using MIDI) is a beep sound (if your computer has a speaker)

Comment: Nice,I'll try this after get back home.