# audio chat using server

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I am developing a voice - chat application
**Flow is Sender -Server-Many clients**

Their will be 2 way communication between all of them 
I have samples of both sender and receiver ready and working fine.

but problem is that I want

**One person will be host of conference**
having access over mic of other participants,

And another issue is that their will be only one mic ON at a time
Is that possible?
please help me!!!

Comment: Please try it a bit yourself before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate `Thread` on `server` to receive audio file from **first computer** and send the file to **other computer**

Comment: will you please post some code for the threading ...

Comment: @GauravDhawale: post your code here (only the logical things) which you have done. So that I can help you on that.

Answer (score 0):

First, your question is kinda general, you have not mentioned a particular problem. 
Second, to accomplish this task you need use Networking Sockets, I/O audio streams and as Mohammad Faisal mentioned threads.

Sound proccessing : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/TOC.html
Networking : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/TOC.html 
Threads : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ 
Java IO : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

check this answer too.

[How can I play sound in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general, which is why it was down voted. There are countless ways of doing what you want, but I think the easiest way for you to approach it is by using Jetty. Jetty is a Java frameworks which enable you to encapsulate your service in a stand-alone server, without all the hassle of actually managing a server.

Comment: I have done that using Socket ,,,,...Thankx for suggestions