# Wanting to add a simple sound to a little project with a separate class, in java

Tags: java, audio

i am making a little java project, it is my first and i just started of programming 2 days ago, i have pretty much no programming knowledge and i need some help with it.
I am trying to add a sound into it, at the end, in a separate class, and i don't know how to perform this. (Sorry if my english is bad)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Counter{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.print("Type Starting number: ");
    String sInput = scanner.nextLine();
    int input = Integer.parseInt(sInput);

    System.out.print("Type Ending number: ");
    String aInput = scanner.nextLine();
    int input2 = Integer.parseInt(aInput);
    if (input <= input2) {
    System.out.println("ERROR, invalid input, please try again");
    main(args);     
    }
    else {

    for (n = input; n >= input2; n--)
    {
    try
        {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
        }
        System.out.print(n + ", ");
    };
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    try
        {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
        }
        System.out.print("BOOM");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    return;
}
}
}
```

Comment: There is pretty good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java

Comment: Here is a good example [Java Sound info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info)

Comment: Thank you Pawet Piecyk, it reall helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Java AWT (Abstract Window Toolkit) is for rendering Graphics, if you want a good audio support, you'll need other APIs. You could start with Java Sound API: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html