# Exception stating " Resetting to invalid mark " comes while marking an inputStream and resetting it, for Large files.?

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream

I am using InputStream object to calculate Md5 of some file.
I mark the stream 
Later I reset the stream. However for large files the following exception comes...

```
inStreamLatestFile.mark(0);
checkSumCalculated = MD5CheckSumCalculator.calculateMD5CheckSum(inStreamLatestFile);
inStreamLatestFile.reset();
```

The exception

```
.Md5ValidationAggrStrat ||**Error in calculating checksum:: java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark**
                        ||java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark
                        ||at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:437)
                        ||at com.amadeus.apt.ib.modules.func.map.camel.strategy.Md5ValidationAggrStrategy.aggregate(Md5ValidationAggrStrategy.java:81)
                        ||at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.onAggregation(AggregateProcessor.java:365)
                        ||at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.doAggregation(AggregateProcessor.java:245)
                        ||at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregateProcessor.process(AggregateProcessor.java:201)
                        ||at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
                        ||at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
```

---

I have tried closing the stream and reopening it this way.. just to get some exceptions as follows::

```
 try {
        inStreamLatestFile= ExchangeHelper.getMandatoryInBody(
                  oldExchange, InputStream.class);

        //inStreamLatestFile.mark(0);
        checkSumCalculated = MD5CheckSumCalculator.calculateMD5CheckSum(inStreamLatestFile);

        //closing the inputStream of the latest file
        if(inStreamLatestFile != null){
            try {
                inStreamLatestFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error occurred in closing the stream :: "+ e.getMessage());
            }
        }


        tempInputStream= ExchangeHelper.getMandatoryInBody(
                  oldExchange, InputStream.class);
        oldExchange.getIn().setBody(tempInputStream);
```

However the following exception comes when I try to resuse the newly retrived InputStream.

```
 caught: java.io.IOException: Stream closed: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
```

Comment: Is it possible the `calculateMD5CheckSum` marks the stream as well?

Comment: Thanks very much for addressing the issue..
No, it is a third party Api and I have no control over it. This method only changes the inputStream and hence I need to mark and reset the stream, as I need it later...

Comment: It's possibly that `getMandatoryInBody` returns the same stream instance every time. I don't know that API.

Comment: Yes this could be an issue.{I am working on apache camel framework} 
So basically it boils down to this question that,  How to create a duplicate inputStream such that the objects are different instances.. ??

Comment: You can read the original `InputStream` into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Copy the `bytes` in that stream into a new `ByteArrayInputStream`. Pass that to the MD5 calculator. The create a new `ByteArrayInputStream` again with the same bytes and pass that to whatever else you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using a `BufferedInputStream` because its source code for `reset()` method is

```
public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
    getBufIfOpen(); // Cause exception if closed
    if (markpos < 0)
        throw new IOException("Resetting to invalid mark"); // exception you are getting
    pos = markpos;
}
```

The following call

```
MD5CheckSumCalculator.calculateMD5CheckSum(inStreamLatestFile);
```

must be doing something to the `markPos`.

If you have no control over it, just reopen the stream. If you can't reopen the stream, ie. you're retrieving the same instance every time, consider using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`

You can read the original `InputStream` into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Copy the bytes in that stream into a new `ByteArrayInputStream`. Pass that to the MD5 calculator. Then create a new `ByteArrayInputStream` again with the same bytes and pass that to whatever else you need.

Comment: @Kumar How did you originally initialize `inStreamLatestFile`? Just close it and reinitialize it.

Comment: You are reusing the same closed stream, not the reinitialized one.