# Add sound to my basic 'Sound Adventure' game

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, javafx

How can I add sound to my basic 'Sound Adventure' game?

I am a beginner and I want to make a basic sound adventure game. (Yes you heard it right, Sound Adventure.)

I know basics of Java and I can code text adventures, but I don't know how Sound works in Java quite yet. I've seen tutorials over the internet and they don't seem to work.
I am ready to change the format of my sound. (It's currently .mp3)
Also, I am using JDK 7 with Eclipse Kepler. (If that helps.)

Here's my code so far:

```
package everything;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declarations
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name To Start...");
    Scanner temp = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = temp.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Okay " + name + ", Let's Get Started!");
    System.out.println("Press N To Start The Game...");
    while(!"N".equals(temp.nextLine())){
        System.out.println("I Asked For The Letter N, Was It So Hard? Try Again!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You could start with the [Sound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/) trail or if you want to stick with MP3, have a look at [JLayer by JavaZoom](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html).  Try something and see what works..

Answer (score 0):

There's literally tons of resources with a simple Google Search.

**Using JavaFX Framework**

Simply use an instance of [AudioClip](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html). This one is very suitable for just playing single short sounds.

```
AudioClip plonkSound = new AudioClip("http://somehost/path/plonk.aiff");
plonkSound.play();
```

**Using Standard Java API**

Standard Java API is a little more painful, I don't have any experience with it but this piece of code has 60+ Upvotes on this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26318/995548).

```
public static synchronized void playSound(final String url) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
  // The wrapper thread is unnecessary, unless it blocks on the
  // Clip finishing; see comments.
    public void run() {
      try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
          Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/sounds/" + url));
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start(); 
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }).start();
}
```