# Java Sound API on Windows 7

Tags: java, audio, windows-7

I found this TestCode at http://www.tutorials.de/threads/java-einen-sound-abspielen.17178/
It's working on OSX but not on my PC Win7. Are there any issues with the Sound API on Win7?
I have several Sound Devices installed (integerated and FireWire AudioInterface) and tried both and heared nothing.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;

/*
 * SoundTest.java
 *
 * Created on 1. August 2003, 21:06
 */

/**
 *
 * @author  Administrator
 */
public class SoundTest {

    /** Creates a new instance of SoundTest */
    public SoundTest() {
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("sample.wav"));
            AudioFormat af     = audioInputStream.getFormat();
            int size      = (int) (af.getFrameSize() * audioInputStream.getFrameLength());
            byte[] audio       = new byte[size];
            DataLine.Info info      = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, af, size);
            audioInputStream.read(audio, 0, size);

           // for(int i=0; i < 32; i++) {
                Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                clip.open(af, audio, 0, size);
                clip.start();
           // }
        }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

    }

}
```

Thanks for replies!

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You took a bad example, thats mixing up code from two different approaches (reading the audiostream yourself versus letting clip handle the stream).

The top answer here [How can I play sound in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305) shows how to play via Clip.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 7 I recommend trying the JavaFX APIs. They are way more advanced and compatible across platforms. You are not limited to the web when using JavaFX, before anyone asks.