# Drain method in Java's Clip class

Tags: java

I am creating a short clip and then play it, calling the `start()` method. I then call the `drain()` method to block the execution until the clip playback is completed. However when running several times the code below, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not, and the sound stops randomly before the end.

```
Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(null);
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 8, 1, true, false);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
try {
    // Create a sound of 1 second
    Clip clip = (Clip)mixer.getLine(info);
    byte[] b = new byte[44100];
    for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
        b[i] = (byte) (50*Math.sin(i/10.0));

    clip.open(format, b, 0, b.length);
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start();
    clip.drain();
} catch(LineUnavailableException lue) { lue.printStackTrace(); }
```

So my question is: is this a bug? or did I misunderstand the `drain()` method?

Answer (score 0):

It seems clip.start() sometimes returns immediately before Start event occurs by a bug(?), and in this case drain has no effect. By a workaround we can use Listener to catch START event:

**Workaround solution:**

```
Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(null);
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 8, 1, true, false);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
try {
    // Create a sound of 1 second
    Clip clip = (Clip)mixer.getLine(info);

    //Workaround part 1
    clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
        @Override
        public void update(LineEvent event) {
            if (event.getType() == Type.START)
                synchronized (clip) {
                    clip.notify();
                }
        }
    });

    byte[] b = new byte[44100];
    for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
        b[i] = (byte) (50*Math.sin(i/10.0));

    clip.open(format, b, 0, b.length);
    clip.setFramePosition(0);

    //Workaround part 2
    synchronized (clip) {
        clip.start();
        clip.wait();
        System.out.println("Started");
    }
    clip.drain();
    System.out.println("Drained");
} catch(LineUnavailableException | InterruptedException lue) { lue.printStackTrace(); }
```