# How can one make an audio player for desktop having the knowledge of basic java?

Tags: java, project, audio-player

I've learned basic java that means the OOP concept,loop,array,variable and some other stuffs.Currently I'm learning thread and I want to make an audio player for desktop using java for my class project.Since I've never made this sort of thing before,can you please suggest me any guideline.I guess it won't be that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't be too hard. Considering you want to do this project to learn, you should break it in several steps. The simplest audio player would be a command line one. You'll need to parse command line arguments and then play the audio.

- [How can I play sound in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java)

You can make it single-threaded as well or if you want to learn threads, you can play the sound in separate thread and wait for the thread to end from the main thread.

You can complicate it further by giving it a list of files that it can play in order or repeat the list when it ends, or even implement the shuffle of the list. Again not a big project and you can still learn some more things.

After this you can implement a simple GUI for your player. Essentially the playing sound building blocks are there. You can validate if your code is well encapsulated. If you did everything in a reusable manner you should be able to just reuse what you wrote for the console player, but if not, then this is a good opportunity to learn from your mistakes and think hard how you could have design the application so that you could have used all your code in both applications.

I guess that your question was downvoted because the best answer to your question is to just do it and try things out. You'll learn a lot in the process.