# sun.audio not working when build

Tags: java, audio

Hey I'm trying to implement some sounds in my Java Program. Within Eclipse it works pretty nice, but when I've build it I get the

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/audio/AudioStream error.
```

Following is the code:

```
    try {
        InputStream music = new FileInputStream(file);
        AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(music);

        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);

    }catch(Exception e) {
        Log.append(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Anyone knows what the problem is or how i can fix this?

Comment: When do you get the error? Where are you running the code, what JVM, what version?

Comment: I'm using java jdk & jre 9.0.4. And i get the Error when i'm starting the Exported Runnable jar. When i'm starting with eclipse it works..

Comment: You're using an internal package (sun.audio.*)  in JDK9. JDK9 is much stricter about that than earlier releases. You shouldn't use the `sun.audio.*` package; there's an official API in the `javax.sound` package. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
InputStream music = new FileInputStream(file);
```

try putting:

```
InputStream music = new FileInputStream(new File (file));
```

. Also, you might not have put the songs file path in the java code.