# How to execute a task or command after another task even if it failed

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a rather long running task in sbt and would like to be notified audibly after it finished, **even it if failed**. I got partially there with this crudeness:

```scala
lazy val ding = taskKey[Unit]("plays a ding sound")
ding := {
  Seq("play", "-q", "/…/SmallGlockA.wav").run
}
```

I invoke aforementioned task like such:

```
sbt> ;test;ding
```

And while this works well if the task succeeded, it will of course not play the sound if the task failed, which – given that it's tests – is likely.

Any ideas how I can work around this? It doesn't have to be pretty or super robust – this will not get committed, it will just be a local thing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to create an `AutoPlugin` for sbt that does what you need.

Create a new file in `project` folder named `DingPlugin.scala` with following content

```scala
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt.PluginTrigger.AllRequirements
import sbt._

object DingPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  private def wavPath = "/path/to/wav"
  private def playSound(wav: String) = ???

  override def trigger = AllRequirements

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    Test / test := (Test / test).andFinally(playSound(wavPath)).value
  )
}
```

The main point is the method `andFinally` [that](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html#andFinally)

> defines a new task that runs the original task and evaluates a side effect regardless of whether the original task succeeded. The result of the task is the result of the original task

The implementation of `playSound` is derived from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305/how-can-i-play-sound-in-java) with the following code

```scala
  private def playSound(wav: String): Unit = {
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream
    import java.io.FileInputStream
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem
    val clip = AudioSystem.getClip
    val inputStream =
      AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(wav))
      )
    clip.open(inputStream)
    clip.start()
    Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength / 1000)
  }
```

Now, you can just run `sbt test` and it will play a sound regardless of whether test succeeded or not.